# Residue of Rankin Selberg L-function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, l-functions

Let $f$ be a normalized holomorphic cusp form with weight $k$, level $N$. The Fourier expansion of $f$ can be written as
\begin{align*}
f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda_f(n)n^{(k-1)/2} e^{2\pi inz}
\end{align*}
The Rankin-Selberg convolution is defined as $L(f\times f) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda_f(n)^2}{n^s}$ for $\Re s>1$. How to calculate the residue at $s=1$ i.e. $\mathrm{Res}_{s=1}L(f\times f)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 2):

The integral representation of $L(s,f\times f)$ (with suitable normalization) was shown (by Rankin and by Selberg, in 1939), to be obtained by integrating $|f|^2$ against the Eisenstein series $E_s$. If we have the normalizations set up appropriately, then the residue at the first pole is the residue of that integral, which is the integral of $|f|^2$ against the residue of $E_s$ at $s=1$ (a constant, etc.) So, up to normalization (which is not so hard to nail down), that first residue is the integral of $|f|^2$...

In addition to the two papers from 1939, by now most introductions to modular forms include this computation. I treat the simplest case in a small essay [http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/basic_rankin_selberg.pdf](http://www.math.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/v/basic_rankin_selberg.pdf)

Comment: Can you give me a reference, where the calculation has shown?